# Play-Rest api with java - object is not a member of package

Tags: java, rest, playframework-2.0

I have a problem, I cant load my web because this error appears:

***object UsersServices is not a member of package controllers***

I use rest api :

```
# Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~

# Home page
GET     /                           controllers.Assets.at(path="/public/view",file="index.html")

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET  /public/*file        controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)


GET /api/users            controllers.UsersServices.getUsers()
```

and the function in java is very basic:

```
public static Result getUsers(){
        return ok(Json.toJson(Test);
    }
```

I rely doesn't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the info you have supplied, it would appear you need to have something like:

```
package controllers;
imports...

public class UsersServices extends Controller {

  public Result getUsers() {
  ...
```